# If an object is heated, does the curvature of the object at a point effect how heat flows out at that point?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, curvature

For example: while expediting, I have to move little football/oval shaped bowls containing food. I want to hold it in such a way that, when moving it from station 1 to station 2, I have the least amount of heat transferred  to my fingers. Does less heat flow out from the sides than the tips, or is it the other way around?

This question is additionally partially inspired by how electric charge builds up in regions with greater curvature

Answer (score 1):

the rate of heat transfer depends on the surface area available, the conductivity and thickness of the wall material, and the temperature difference between the inside and the outside surfaces of the wall. Geometrically, the tips of the football-shaped food containers have more exterior surface area to them in relation to the volume of hot food in their immediate vicinity. This means it will be easier for the tips to lose heat and that after being filled with hot food and allowed to equilibrate for a minute or so, the tips will be cooler than the sides of the bowl. However, for a bowl that is only slightly football-shaped, the difference will be small, and if the bowl walls are thick relative to the overall dimensions of the bowl then the difference will be smaller still.

Finally, note that if the bowls are pre-heated in an oven before being filled with food, then the tips will start hot and the effects I summarize above will be relatively smaller. From the standpoint of what you will feel with your fingers when handling a preheated ceramic food container that is slightly football-shaped and has walls that are thick, you'll probably burn them no matter how you hold the bowls.